# Trouble getting VNC to run on boot

Tags: boot, vnc

I set up the VNC using [this setup guide](http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server).

Seems to go well on the whole, though I do get the error

```
update-rc.d: error: unable to read /etc/init.d//etc/init.d/vncboot
```

following the next step seems to fix it.

However, when I reboot the pi I get this error:

```
/etc/init.d/vncboot: line 23: /usr/bin/vncserver :0 No such file or directory
/etc/init.d/vncboot: line 24: $'\302\240': command not found
```

I was wondering if anyone else has encountered this, or knows how to solve is as I have NO idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some looking at this, I finally managed to get it work using:

http://www.myraspberrypiexperience.com/start-vnc-automatically/

(after reinstalling raspbian)

Hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue!

**Edit:**
The site above is now dead. You can view the page via archive.org at https://web.archive.org/web/20150516050232/http://www.myraspberrypiexperience.com/start-vnc-automatically/

Unfortunately, the images don't show.

`sudo nano /etc/init.d/tightvncserver`, then enter this:

```
# First configure the user you want to run this under – this will generally be pi, unless you’ve created your own users
export USER='pi'

eval cd ~$USER

# Check the state of the command – this’ll either be start or stop 
case "$1" in
  start)
    # if it’s start, then start vncserver using the details below
    su $USER -c '/usr/bin/vncserver :1 -geometry 1280×800 -depth 16 -pixelformat rgb565'
    echo "Starting vncserver for $USER "
    ;;
  stop)
    # if it’s stop, then just kill the process
    pkill Xtightvnc
    echo "vncserver stopped"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/vncserver {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Afterwards, run this:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/tightvncserver
sudo update-rc.d tightvncserver defaults
```

Comment: Please copy the relevant text to keep the question relevant.